# Which format use in to_char (text) function in postgres

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I am using to_char(message) function in postgressql.message having data type as text ..how I can convert this in postgressql

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Take a look at the function definitions/signature here [Data formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-formatting.html). You are missing an argument.